# tf.data.Dataset.from_generator() for network with multiple inputs

Tags: tensorflow, keras

So I'm trying to build a model that takes hundreds of inputs, each input being a row of an image (it's not really an image, the data has just been put in that form).

So I have two generators, one that creates a single X training example, and one that loads a single Y training example. The y generator works fine, but the X generator gives me problems. I feel it's to do with how I've specific output_types, but nothing seems to work:

Code snippet:

```
def x_data_gen():
    for i in range(num_exp):
        filepath = fns[i]
        im = Image.open(filepath)
        im = np.array(im, dtype=np.float32)
        inputs = []
        for n in range(num_inputs):
            inputs.append( np.reshape(im[n,:], (1,6000,1)) )
        yield inputs

def y_data_gen():
    for i in range(num_exp):
        filepath = fns_y
        im = Image.open(filepath)
        y = np.reshape(np.array(im, dtype=np.float32), (1,6000,1))
        yield y

x_types = [ tf.float32 for _ in range(num_exp) ]
y_types = tf.float32

inputs = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(x_data_gen, output_types=x_types)
y = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(y_data_gen, output_types=y_types)
```

error

```
  File "start_spikes2_mutliinput2.py", line 67, in <module>
    inputs = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(x_data_gen, output_types=x_types)
  File "C:\Users\wmkc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py", line 535, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\wmkc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\dataset_ops.py", line 904, in from_generator
    output_signature = nest.map_structure_up_to(output_types,
  File "C:\Users\wmkc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\util\nest.py", line 444, in map_structure_up_to
    results = [func(*tensors) for tensors in zip(*all_flattened_up_to)]
  File "C:\Users\wmkc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\util\nest.py", line 444, in <listcomp>
    results = [func(*tensors) for tensors in zip(*all_flattened_up_to)]
  File "C:\Users\wmkc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_spec.py", line 56, in __init__
    self._dtype = dtypes.as_dtype(dtype)
  File "C:\Users\wmkc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py", line 647, in as_dtype
    raise TypeError("Cannot convert value %r to a TensorFlow DType." %
TypeError: Cannot convert value [tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32] to a TensorFlow DType.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this loop in your x_data_gen()

```
for n in range(num_inputs):
    a,b = im[n,:].shape
    inputs.append( np.reshape(im[n,:], (1,a*b,1)))
```